# Find temperature unit from settings app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I am working on an iOS app in Swift 3, I need to get user preferred unit for temperature from settings app (Celsius or Fahrenheit). I tried finding a solution for it but no success. :(
Can anyone suggest how to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wrote an extension for it, check it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65647650/1290278

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the MeasurementFormatter in swift.

This method does not use any private API's. Remember to run this on an actual device(iOS 10+) as the simulator does not have that option.

```
    let formatter = MeasurementFormatter.init()
    let temperature = Measurement.init(value: 37.0, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
    let localTemperature = formatter.string(from: temperature)
    if(localTemperature.contains("C")) {
        print("UNIT IS °C")
    } else {
        print("UNIT IS °F")
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `kCFLocaleTemperatureUnitKey` key is not documented. So apple might have problem with that. Please read [this thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/70258) for more. His app was rejected because of this key.

```
let locale = NSLocale.current as NSLocale
let obj = locale.object(forKey: NSLocale.Key(rawValue: "kCFLocaleTemperatureUnitKey"))
print("\(obj!)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose NSLocaleTemperatureUnit of type NSLocaleKey,

```
FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSLocaleKey const NSLocaleTemperatureUnit;
```

Then you will be able to access NSLocale information based on the temperature unit NSLocaleKey.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
__unused id info = [locale objectForKey:NSLocaleTemperatureUnit];
```

For example
[image]

Comment: I found that code on stack-overflow, Can you share swift 3 equivalent, I did not find equivalent for NSLocaleTemperatureUnit in Swift 3

Comment: This is a bad idea if you're going to submit your app into the App store. You will get something like "Error: ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage" in the app review.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified other answers for more elegant option

```
extension Locale {

    var temperatureUnit: UnitTemperature {
        let units: [UnitTemperature] = [.celsius, .fahrenheit, .kelvin]

        let measurement = Measurement(value: 37, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)

        let temperatureString = MeasurementFormatter().string(from: measurement)

        let matchedUnit = units.first { temperatureString.contains($0.symbol) }
        if matchedUnit != nil {
            return matchedUnit!
        }
        
        return usesMetricSystem ? .celsius : .fahrenheit
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working in Polish language with °C and imperial system. The temperatureString is "37 st. C", which is not contains the symbol "°C". I've tried with changing unitStyle on Formatter to .short, but then it's "37°".

Answer (score 0):

Based on others' answers I made it a bit more general

```
protocol LocalizableDimension: Dimension {
    associatedtype T: Dimension
    static var allUnits: [T] { get }
}

extension LocalizableDimension {
    static var current: T {
        let baseUnit = allUnits[0]
        let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
        formatter.locale = .current
        let measurement = Measurement(value: 0, unit: baseUnit)
        let string = formatter.string(from: measurement)
        for unit in allUnits {
            if string.contains(unit.symbol) {
                return unit
            }
        }
        return baseUnit
    }
}
```

This can be generalized even further and make it accept any locale instead of just current and provide similar API than what is available starting on iOS 16 where you can create a dimension from a given locale provided as argument.

To make use of this functionality you still need to conform the relevant dimensions for your domain to this protocol like

```
extension UnitTemperature: LocalizableDimension {
    static let allUnits: [UnitTemperature] = [.celsius, .fahrenheit, .kelvin]
}

extension UnitSpeed: LocalizableDimension {
    static let allUnits: [UnitSpeed] = [.kilometersPerHour, .milesPerHour, .metersPerSecond, .knots]
}
```

With this, you can do

```
UnitTemperature.current // .celsius, .fahrenheit, .kelvin depending on the current locale
```