# Get user preferred temperature setting in macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, foundation, temperature

I'm trying to read the user set system preferences for Temperature unit (Celsius/Fahrenheit).
I was trying to get this data using NSLocale but I cannot find any evidence of a temperature setting in there.

Is it even possible to read this data?

Thanks!

Comment: Dupe: [Determine user's “Temperature Unit” setting on iOS 10 (Celsius / Fahrenheit)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39727075/2415822)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine user's "Temperature Unit" setting on iOS 10 (Celsius / Fahrenheit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727075/determine-users-temperature-unit-setting-on-ios-10-celsius-fahrenheit)

Comment: No duplicate as the linked question addresses iOS while this questions addresses macOS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official API is documented under the [Preferences Utilities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/preferences_utilities):

```
let key = "AppleTemperatureUnit" as CFString
let domain = "Apple Global Domain" as CFString

if let unit = CFPreferencesCopyValue(key, domain, kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, kCFPreferencesAnyHost) as? String {
    print(unit)
} else {
    print("Temperature unit not found")
}
```

If you wonder how I found it, I used the `defaults` utility in the Terminal:

```
> defaults find temperature
Found 1 keys in domain 'Apple Global Domain': {
    AppleTemperatureUnit = Fahrenheit;
}
Found 1 keys in domain 'com.apple.ncplugin.weather': {
    WPUseMetricTemperatureUnits = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a hack, but you can do it this way on macOS 10.12+ and iOS 10+:

```
// Create a formatter.
let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()

// Create a dummy temperature, the unit doesn't matter because the formatter will localise it.
let dummyTemp = Measurement(value: 0, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)

let unit = formatter.string(from: dummyTemp).characters.last // -> F
```

This outputs "F" in my playground which defaults to the US locale. But change your locale or use this code on a device and you'll get the locale specific temperature unit - or the string for it anyway.