# Find metric "Speed, Degree, etc..." standard by location

Tags: javascript, api, geolocation, units-of-measurement

I have a program that displays the Weather in the current region of the users' computer.

The problem is that I want to automate the metrics conversion.

so for example in Europe, we measure the heat with **Celsius** and in the USA we measure it with **Fahrenheit**
same goes for **Km/H** and **M/H** in speed respectively.

I want to know if there is a way to know the metric system of a country without having to write a hardcoded table for every country in the world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some operating systems expose an API to find the preferred measurement standard.

- For Android apps, use [`LocaleData.MeasurementSystem`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/LocaleData#getMeasurementSystem(android.icu.util.ULocale))
- For MacOS, use [`CFPreferencesCopyValue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1515500-cfpreferencescopyvalue) ([guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511458/get-user-preferred-temperature-setting-in-macos))
- For Windows, use [`GetLocaleInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/locale/units-of-measurement#units-of-measurement-in-win32)
- For IOS, use [`NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocaleusesmetricsystem) ([guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413144/how-do-i-know-which-is-the-default-measure-system-imperial-or-metric-on-ios))

Otherwise, if you know their location, you can default to Imperial in the United States, Liberia or Myanmar and use Metric in other locations:

[image: The Imperial system is used in the United States, Liberia and Myanmar]

Regardless, you should still allow users to manually choose their preference.