# How do I add a degree symbol as part of a UILabel in iPhone development?

Tags: swift, api, uilabel, openweathermap

I have added the degree symbol to my UILabel but when the app runs it disappears.  I am creating a weather app so it is important that it is formatted correctly.
This is the code I have once the ViewController has loaded.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cityLabel.text = city
    userEnteredNewCityName(city: city)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Here is the code that updates the ViewController

```
func updateWeatherData(json: JSON) {
    if let tempResult = json["main"]["temp"].double {
        weatherDataModel.temperature = Int(tempResult - 273)
        weatherDataModel.city = json["name"].stringValue
        weatherDataModel.condition = json["weather"][0]["id"].intValue
        weatherDataModel.weatherIconName = weatherDataModel.updateWeathericon(condition: weatherDataModel.condition)

        updateUIWithWeatherData()
    } else {
        cityLabel.text = "No data available"
    }

}

func userEnteredNewCityName(city: String){
    let params : [String : String] = ["q" : city, "appid" : APP_ID]
    getWeatherData(url: WEATHER_URL, parameters: params)
}

 //Write the updateUIWithWeatherData method here:


func updateUIWithWeatherData() {
    cityLabel.text = weatherDataModel.city
    temperatureLabel.text = String(weatherDataModel.temperature)
    weatherIcon.image = UIImage(named: weatherDataModel.weatherIconName)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: please provide the code part that you set your "degrees" label's text.

Comment: You should probably use `MeasurementFormatter`.

Comment: i still don't see the "degree" symbol being add. but you could use `temperatureLabel.text = String(weatherDataModel.temperature) + "°"`

Comment: I added the degree symbol in the storyboard.

Comment: @AltBrian that's what i figured. which is fine. but when you set your `temperatureLabel.text = String(weatherDataModel.temperature)` you are overwriting the text that was there prior. So you need to append the String with `+ "°"` as i stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, use `MeasurementFormatter`:

```
let measurement = Measurement(value: weatherDataModel.temperature, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)

let measurementFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
measurementFormatter.unitStyle = .short
measurementFormatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
measurementFormatter.unitOptions = .temperatureWithoutUnit

temperatureLabel.text = measurementFormatter.string(from: measurement)
```

No need to convert to `Int`. The formatter will handle displaying of decimal digits.

As a bonus, you don't have to do the Kelvin to Celsius conversion by yourself:

```
let measurementInKelvin = Measurement(value: weatherDataModel.temperature, unit: UnitTemperature.kelvin)
let measurement = measurementInKelvin.converted(to: .celsius)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are updating your temp label in this line of code:

```
temperatureLabel.text = String(weatherDataModel.temperature)
```

You are simply converting a number into a string overwriting everything that was inserted in label before. If you want to add the degree symbol just do this:

```
temperatureLabel.text = String(weatherDataModel.temperature) + "°"
```

Now, event if is this is the easiest way is not the more robust, because you are not taking into account the *locale* of the user, to understand better let's say the unit of measure, in the US they use Fahrenheit for instance.
To do that is better if you create the string by using a `MeasurementFormatter` or check [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ios-11-swift/9781491992463/ch04.html) . To get the temperature unit check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727075/determine-users-temperature-unit-setting-on-ios-10-celsius-fahrenheit).

```
    let measureFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
    let measurement = Measurement(value: <#your_value#>, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
    let output = measureFormatter.string(from: measurement)
```