# Changing the temperature in my app based on the users preferences

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Right now my app just displays the temperature in Fahrenheit. I would like it so that if the user in their settings (General > Language & Region > Temperature Unit) has it set to Celsius my app would then precede to show that. Sadly I cant think of a way to fix this bug... It seems that I am just stuck on Fahrenheit. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks everyone :)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727075/determine-users-temperature-unit-setting-on-ios-10-celsius-fahrenheit/41263725

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, I am not sure if there is a way to know which temperature system the user prefers, but there is a way to know if he use the metric system (Celsius) or imperial (Fahrenheit).

```
let locale = Locale.current
let isMetric = locale.usesMetricSystem

if isMetric {
   // Use Celsius

} else {
   // Use Fahrenheit

}
```

Comment: If you dont mind me asking, how does it figure out what the user uses? Is this going based off of their location?

Comment: not his location, but the country/region he put when he opened the device for the first time which can be changed later on.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense.. I will have to test it out, it might not work :/ as the biggest problem I have is that I have people in the USA using the app but they want the degrees in Celsius :/ I really do appreciate the help though :)