# Determine users desired temperature units (F/C) from user settings in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, temperature

Does anyone know the current best method to determine the state of the users temperature preference settings? The one under Settings -> General -> Language & Region -> Temperature Unit?

I've seen some older answers but they don't work for me. I'm thinking that the method has changed over the last several years.

Comment: You shouldn't need to know this. Just use a measurement formatter and the temperature will be presented in accordance with the user's settings. In other words, you worry about the value and let the runtime worry about the user-facing presentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determine user's "Temperature Unit" setting on iOS 10 (Celsius / Fahrenheit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39727075/determine-users-temperature-unit-setting-on-ios-10-celsius-fahrenheit). Specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39728894/9223839)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on a physical device (it does not in iOS simulator):

```
let myFormatter = MeasurementFormatter()
let temperature = Measurement(value: 0, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
print(myFormatter.string(from: temperature))
```

If Settings -> General -> Language & Region -> Temperature is set to Fahrenheit it outputs 32°F otherwise 0°C.

If you are interested in the state you should parse the returned string either for "°C" or "°F"

Comment: Anyone know why the temperature units don't work in a simulator?